# Where Clause in MySQL - JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm newbie with mysql and this is my issue. I have a table in database called Room with one of its attribute as Floor. In the Floor column, there are 3 different names ( Walters, Gates, Pension).

I'm trying to fetch figures from table based on the selected floor and this is my query.

```
 String query = "Select * from Rooms where Floor =" + Floor.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

This seems like the right query but i get an error thrown saying Unknown Column 'Walters' in where clause.

What am i not doing right?

Comment: You should be using a prepared statement with a parameter placeholder. Please look at this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: You're not using prepared statements to pass parameters, and thus avoid the need to properly escape parameters. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is not correct, because String should be between to quotes `""` :

```
String query = 
     "Select * from Rooms where Floor = '" + Floor.getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
    //----------------------------------^------------------------------------------^
```

But this not secure, instead read about [Prepared Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid SQL Injection and syntax error :

```
String query = "Select * from Rooms where Floor = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, Floor.getSelectedItem().toString());
pstmt.executeQuery();//then execute the statement
```

Answer (score 1):

strings in a query should be in single quotes, your query should be:

```
Select * from Rooms where Floor = 'Walter';
```

so your code should be:

```
String query = "Select * from Rooms where Floor = '" + Floor.getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
```

It is better to use [PreparedStatements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

`String query =
 "Select * from Rooms where Floor ='" + Floor.getSelectedItem().toString();+"'"`